# bridge network between two linux servers

Tags: linux, networking, centos, bridge

I need to set up following network architecture :

```
                       Internet
                        ^   
+-----------------+     |          +------------------+
|  Centos6-1      |     |          |      Centos6-2   |
|      +---- eth0 + ----+          |                  |
| (br0)|          |                |                  |
|      +---- eth1 +----------------+ eth0             |
+-----------------+                +------------------+
                     ( cable connection )
```

Two public IP's are to be configured like follows :

- **eth0** and **eth1** of **Centos6-1 are to be configured as a bridge with IP1
- **Centos6-1** can be accessed with IP1
- **eth0** of **Centos6-2** is configured with IP2
- any request destined to IP2 will flow through **Centos6-1**

How can i accomplish this feat?

There is a service running in the second server. This service will bind to IP2. what will happen

Edit:

If i do the following in box1:

```
brctl addbr br0
ifdown eth0
ifdown eth1
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 up
ifconfig eth1 0.0.0.0 up
ifconfig br0 IP1 ****
```

would it do what i want?

Comment: Visio? Who needs Visio? Not this guy! +1

Comment: Putting ASCII diagrams in your questions is asking for free +1's on ServerFault -- welcome aboard!

Comment: Hand drawn is the new ASCII diagram of '12!

Comment: if only my superior understood the power of ascii :)

Comment: it will flow thru Centos6-1 but only at the link layer. sort of like using your Centos6-1 as a network switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this blog](http://www.banym.de/linux/centos/setup-bridge-device-on-centos), you can setup bridge under CentOS in this way:

You have to add `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br0`:

```
DEVICE=br0
TYPE=Bridge
BOOTPROTO=static
DNS1=192.168.0.1
GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
IPADDR=192.168.0.100
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
ONBOOT=yes
SEARCH=”example.com”
```

And in the `ifcfg-eth0`:

```
DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=00:1e:90:f3:f0:02
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
IPV6INIT=no
USERCTL=no
BRIDGE=br0
```

ifcfg-eth1 will be similar.

HWADDR you have to have MAC address of eth0, resp. eth1...

Between two servers you have to have [crossover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable) Ethernet cable...

Answer (score 2):

That's not bridging, what you want is simple NAT forwarding.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d IP2 --to-destination internal_IP2 -j DNAT
```

And let the boxes communicate using a private internal_IP pair (internal_IP1, internal_IP2)

Comment: does this leave the packets verbatim or modify packet header? I'm going for link layer because i want my packets intact.

Comment: It changes the destination IP of the incoming packets, and the source IP of the outgoing packets. Why do you think this is a problem ?